# import multiple classes from jar file works for some classes and does not work others

Tags: java, jar

I am try trying to import many classes from many jar files like:

```
    //httpcore-4.4.10.jar
    import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
    import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
    //commons-collections4-4.4.jar
    import org.apache.commons.collections4.ListUtils;
    //httpclient-4.5.10.jar
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPatch;
```

I use the following in the termianl:

```
javac -cp "./apache/libs/*"  MainClass.java
```

May jar files are:
httpcore-4.4.10.jar, commons-collections4-4.4.jar, httpclient-4.5.10.jar

And it compiles correctly and then I try to run the file:

```
java -cp "apache/lib/*" MainClass
```

I get `Error: Could not find or load main class MainClass`

and when I do

```
java MainClass
```

I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase
```

This is strange because I import other classes also from the same jar file and they get loaded

At some point I had different version of the same jar in the lib but I deleted it.

A snippet of the code:

```
public void call_api(String json_str, String json_type) throws Exception {

            CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();

            HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase httpObj;

            json_str = json_str.replaceAll("\'", "\"");
            json_str = json_str.replaceAll("True", "true");
            json_str = json_str.replaceAll("False", "false");
```

it proves that I can get the `CloseableHttpClient` class from the same jar file then it fails in getting  `HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase`

Comment: try `java -cp ".;apache/lib/*" MainClass`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
java -cp "apache/lib/*" MainClass
```

that puts your **libraries** on the classpath.

```
java MainClass
```

that one only puts MainClass on the class path (assuming that sits in the current 
directory).

Meaning: you want that your classpath contains **all** locations that hold required classes: the directories with libraries and the directories with **your** classes.

Try something like

```
java -cp "./:apache/lib/*" MainClass
```

or something. The key thing is: ensure that *all* needed directories show up on the classpath (not so sure about my above example, as `apache/lib` smells fishy: you probably should start with absolute paths here)!

Comment: Thank you very much! By trying this `java -cp "./:apache/lib/*" MainClass` I got the problem solved, I was trying `java -cp "apache/lib/*" MainClass` and it never worked but it worked for `javac` like `javac -cp "apache/lib/*" MainClass.java` I don't really understand why

Comment: @RodwanBakkar The javac command is most likely looking for your java sources in the current directory. Therefore **that** command only needs the libraries on the class path. When you want to **run** your class, you need your class+libraries.